# Inserting Large Amounts of data into MySQL Table only inserts 1 row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am pulling data from a IDX/RETS server and trying to insert the data into my own MySQL data base using php.

The data comes in as multiple associative arrays and i loop through them entering each array into its own row.

The table itself has 215 columns, in my first test I only pull 10 records/array's and after running my script I only get 1 row entered.

I have been able to get all 10 rows to insert but only by reducing the number of columns to about 6. For what ever reason when trying to enter all 215 columns of the 10 records it keeps timing out.

I have tried:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
```

&

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

I have also tried entering these values into my php.ini file but what ever i do the script only seems to run for about 15-30 seconds.

Is there something else I am missing or should be doing when entering so many columns??

My code is just a simple while loop that is looping through the arrays. And my insert is like this:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO rets_property_residentialproperty";
        $sql .= " (`".implode("`, `", array_keys($my_array))."`)";
        $sql .= " VALUES ('".implode("', '", $my_array)."') ";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Are you running it via a browser or command line?

Comment: Currently am testing in a browser, but this script will be running via a Cron Job once in production about 2-3 times a day to update the db.

Comment: First make sure you have restarted the webserver after changing your php.ini then check error log as it may be running out of memory

Comment: @Anigel thanks for that I did forget to reset my server, I am not on the ball today!

Comment: `echo "INSERT INTO rets_property_residentialproperty";...` to see what's being passed through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, don't mix **mysql** and **mysqli** interface functions. The call to `mysql_error` should be replaced with a call to `mysqli_error`.

Not at all clear what's "timing out".

Most likely, the INSERT statement is throwing an error, the code is going into the `die`, and the problem is with the `mysql_error` function. Get that function replaced with **`mysqli_error`**, and I venture that you'll get a MySQL error.

```
    ... or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
                    ^       ^^^^^^
```

---

Likely, the underlying issue is a SQL syntax error. For example, one of the values in the array may contain a character that needs to be escaped, such as a single quote.

(But, I'm just guessing here.)

For debugging, you might consider echoing out the SQL text

```
    echo $sql;
```

before the call to `mysqli_query`. (Then you can compare the error to the actual SQL text that you intended to send to the database.

To handle single quotes and other "dangerous" characters in the values, (to close a gaping SQL Injection vulnerability) you'd either need to call `mysqli_real_escape_string` on each of the array values, before the value is included in the SQL text. Or, use a prepared statement with bind placeholders, and then supply the array values as the values for the bind placeholders.

Comment: There goes my edit. DB connection `($dbcon)` should be passed to `mysqli_error()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php `string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Your edit was inadvertently overwritten, when I saved my edit. I was referencing the function by name, not giving an example of the syntax; I omitted the opening and close parens, so as not to give the impression it was complete syntax. (I also didn't show arguments in my references to the names of the `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` functions.)

Comment: LOL, yes I was under that impression that that is what happened.

Comment: Thanks for that totally missed the sqli_error(). So after updating with correct function I dont get any actual errors. However when i echo out the SQL I get:

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Lakefront Property,Main House Approx 8500 Sf. 2 Levels,Guest House 1200 Sf. 4 Ca' at line 1

Id dont see any bad characters here though?

Comment: I have now tried escaping the text that appears to be the problem but still no luck. I can see that in the text there is ' characters but mysqli_real_escape_string doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: If you `echo $sql;` that should return the contents of the string containing the SQL statement. That error message is being returned from the `mysqli_error` function _not_ the echo of the SQL text. To properly escape the values, when they're included as literals in the SQL statement, you'd need to include the return from `mysqli_real_escape_string` for each value in the array. (But if it were me doing it, I would just use a **prepared statement** with bind placeholders, and bind the values in the array, rather than escaping the values and including them as literals in the SQL text.)

Comment: Ended up being apostrophes in one of the text fields i was pulling. Cheers,